# how to ignore UICollectionViewCell size on storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uistoryboard

I have cell size on storyboard:
[image: Screenshot1]
But I want to set cell size in the code based on device's screen size, and I call next delegate method:

```
extension GraphicsViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 0.675 * self.view.frame.size.width, height: 0.625 * self.view.frame.size.height)
    }

}
```

I call this cell's method:

```
func draw(coordinates: [CGPoint]?) {
        let width = self.temperatureGraphicView.frame.size.width
        let height = self.temperatureGraphicView.frame.size.height
        temperatureBackGroundView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        temperatureBackGroundView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        temperatureBackGroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        humidityBackGroundView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        humidityBackGroundView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        humidityBackGroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        let verticalLines = setFramesArrays().0
        let horizontalLines = setFramesArrays().1
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: verticalLines.count - 1, by: 2) {
            drawFrame(fromPoint: verticalLines[i], toPoint: verticalLines[i + 1], graphicNumber: 0)
            drawFrame(fromPoint: verticalLines[i], toPoint: verticalLines[i + 1], graphicNumber: 1)
        }
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: horizontalLines.count - 1, by: 2) {
            drawFrame(fromPoint: horizontalLines[i], toPoint: horizontalLines[i + 1], graphicNumber: 0)
            drawFrame(fromPoint: horizontalLines[i], toPoint: horizontalLines[i + 1], graphicNumber: 1)
        }
    }
```

Frames of my Views gets based on cell's frame on storyboard, and my grid drawing incorrect:
[image: Screenshot2]

And when I reload data in collection, I have this:
[image: Screenshot3]
My question is how to ignore cell frame on storyboard and set it programmatically? And what can I do with input views frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are calling `draw` function in `collectionView(collectionView:indexPath:)` datasource method.
you have to call `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` **before** the line to make all the subviews within the cell relayout using the new size.